# C++ matrix problem : incorrect output for transpose matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, matrix, transpose

I have to write a program to allow a user to input the number of rows and the number    of columns of a matrix.  The program will then construct the transpose of the   matrix and display the transpose to the user, it is also supposed to display the trace and determinant of the matrix. I am having a problem with the output for the transpose, whenever the matrix is not a perfect square I get random numbers.
This is my code:

```
int main()
{
int matrix[10][10];
int row, column, i, j;
int temp = 0;

//size of matrix
cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
cin >> row;

cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
cin >> column;

// read the matrix values ( original matrix )

cout << "Enter the elements: \n";

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
        cin >> matrix[i][j];

cout << "Matrix: \n";

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)

        cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;

}

// transpose the matrix values ( the matrix transposed )

cout << "Transpose of a Matrix: \n";

for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < column; i++)

        cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
}

// trace of a matrix
int trace = 0;
if (row == column)
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)

            trace += matrix[i][i];
            cout << "Trace of a Matrix: \n";
            cout << trace << endl;
    }
else
{
    cout << "The trace will not be computed \n"
         << "The given matrix is not a perfect square" << endl;
}

// determinant of Matrix

int det = 0;
if (row == 2 && column == 2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)

            cout << "Determinant of the Matrix: \n";
            det = ((matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[1][0] * matrix[0][1]));
            cout << det << endl;

            
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "The determinant will not be computed \n"
         << "The given matrix is not a square" << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

If I were to enter 3 rows and 2 columns and random elements my output looks like this:

```
 Enter number of rows: 3
 Enter number of columns : 2
 Enter the elements:
 1 5 6 -4 2 3
 Matrix:
 1 5
 6 -4
 2 3
 Transpose of a Matrix:
 1 6
 5 -4
 -858993460 -858993460
 The trace will not be computed
 The given matrix is not a perfect square
 The determinant will not be computed
 The given matrix is not a square
```

Is there something wrong in my code that causes -858993460 and -858993460 to come up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this when printing the transpose (note the upper bounds for the loops have been swapped compared to your code) :

```
for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
```

The reason you got "random elements", is because your code was reading and printing the contents of memory that hadn't been initialized yet.

Eg. in your example output, the first value `-858993460` was obtained from `matrix[2][0]` (with `j == 2` and `i == 0`), but that slot hadn't been filled with anything (the original matrix only occupies `0 <= i <= 2` and `0 <= j <= 1`). Similarly, the second value `-858993460` was obtained from `matrix[2][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing parts of the memory, that have not been written to while reading in the matrix elements.

Instead of changing what i and j represent when printing the matrix, just change the order of the for loops from the order in that you were reading the elements.

```
cout << "Transpose of a Matrix: \n";

for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
```